# Rails cannot find Gemfile when trying to create new app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails and I try to create a new app (on MacOS). I've installed Ruby, Rails and bundler through rvm.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
$ gem -v
2.6.10
$ bundler -v
Bundler version 1.14.5
```

I try to create the app like this:

```
$ mkdir au5
$ cd au5
$ rvm use ruby-2.4.0@au5 --ruby-version --create
$ gem install rails
$ rails new au5
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@au5/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:24:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@au5/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:29:in `default_lockfile'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@au5/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler.rb:307:in `default_lockfile'
    from /Users/user/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

**Edit 1:**
rails -v gives me:

```
$ gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-5.0.1
Parsing documentation for rails-5.0.1
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
$ rails -v
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@au5/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:24:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@au5/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:29:in `default_lockfile'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@au5/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler.rb:307:in `default_lockfile'
    from /Users/user/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

**Edit 2:** Tried to create empty Gemfile:

```
$ touch Gemfile
$ echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'" > Gemfile
$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.14.5
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.14.5
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
$ rails new au5
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@au5/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:24:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@au5/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:29:in `default_lockfile'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@au5/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler.rb:307:in `default_lockfile'
    from /Users/user/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

**Edit 3:** These are the files in my project folder:

```
$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 user  1694527156  170 Feb 28 22:28 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 user  1694527156  272 Feb 28 22:26 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user  1694527156    4 Feb 28 22:26 .ruby-gemset
-rw-r--r--  1 user  1694527156   11 Feb 28 22:26 .ruby-version
-rw-r--r--  1 user  1694527156   30 Feb 28 22:28 Gemfile
```

Comment: and the folder `au5` is empty?

Comment: ---Yes. I tried to add an empty Gemfile, didn't help either.--- See my next answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem empty because rails is invoking `bin/rails` (last line in your stacktrace).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was wrong. I have three files: .ruby-gemset, .ruby-version, Gemfile. There is no ```bin``` folder though.

Comment: Can you post the output of `gem env` and `bundle env` as well as `echo $BUNDLE_GEMFILE`?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating an empty `Gemfile`?

```
touch Gemfile
echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'" > Gemfile
```

Also make sure to install `bundler`

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue still persists. See my edit.

Answer (score -1):

With rbenv, there is a rehash function that fixes (among other things) the paths associated with installed gems. When you install a gem that has executable scripts, rbenv can sometimes get confused and needs to have the environment refreshed.

I don't know if rvm has a similar mechanism; I don't have it installed and a cursory google doesn't show anything. But you might want to start looking there.

(and consider switching to rbenv, it seems to be far less quirky)

Comment: There's no rehash for `rvm`